# Bootstrap and conditional image sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, image-size

With desktop images that span the width of the browser, we'd like to display smaller images for the slider in our Bootstrap/Classic ASP site. The site is currently resizing the hi-res image using Bootstrap's built-in 'img-responsive' class, but we feel we could improve the experience if we loaded smaller images for viewports under 768 pixels and the existing images for 768 pixels and above.

Here's the basic markup for the slider:

```
<div class="item active">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="img/slide_001_1900x650.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-content">
            <h3><a href="#">First slide</a></h3>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="img/slide_002_1900x650.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-content">
            <h3><a href="#">Second slide</a></h3>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="img/slide_003_1900x650.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-content">
            <h3><a href="#">Third slide</a></h3>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Rewriting the src doesn't appear to be as good of an idea as it seems, since it essentially processes double the HTTP requests. Adaptive Images requires PHP and this site is built using Classic ASP, so I'm trying to find out if there's possibly a jQuery script that can leveraged that would work similar to Adaptive Images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any server-side or JavaScript support at all for this. You just need to change your images to be CSS `background-image`s instead of inline in the HTML, then let CSS and the browser determine what you need.

#### Step 1 - Remove inline `img` tags

```
<div class="item active">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="carousel-content">
        <h3><a href="#">First slide</a></h3>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="carousel-content">
        <h3><a href="#">Second slide</a></h3>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="carousel-content">
        <h3><a href="#">Third slide</a></h3>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

#### Step 2 - Use CSS `background-image` to reinstate images

You might have to use `background-position` to position them how you'd like.

```
div.item {
  height: 8em;
  width: 36em;  
  background-image: url("http://www.thecatman.info/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/five-cute-kittens.png")   
}
```

#### Step 3 - Add a responsive version

Too many kittens when we drop below 768px? No problem; add this:

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  div.item {
    width: 18em;
    background-image:url("http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/img-thing?.out=jpg&size=l&tid=44246076")
  }
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p022652f/) to demonstrate it.

Comment: In your example, you're adding the low-res image using a media query. That means the user's browser has to download the high-res image after all. It is better to work mobile first.

Comment: True. But it shows the idea of driving it all from CSS. Obviously the "Step 2" CSS can be wrapped in a media query as well to prevent unnecessary downloads.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <div class="item active">
            <div class="carousel-content">
                <h3><a href="#">First slide</a></h3>
            </div>
         <div class="img_disp" style="display:none">
             <img src="img/slide_001_1900x650.jpg" height="15px" width="15px">
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
            <div class="carousel-content">
                <h3><a href="#">Second slide</a></h3>
            </div>
           <div class="img_disp" style="display:none">
             <img src="img/slide_002_1900x650.jpg" height="15px" width="15px">
           </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
            <div class="carousel-content">
                <h3><a href="#">Third slide</a></h3>
            </div>
          <div class="img_disp" style="display:none">
              <img src="img/slide_003_1900x650.jpg" height="15px" width="15px">
          </div>

    </div>
//this is the jquery part
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(document).on('click','h3>a',function(event){
               event.preventDefault();
               $(this).parents('.item').find('.img_disp').show();
         });
    });
    </sript>
```

the image sizes can be varied by changing the height and the width of your desire. Try this code.